# transform a 2 array value in a matrix format

Tags: java

i have a 2 array with that display value of a matrix .I have use 2 for loops and a string builder to display the values.The problem is that the values are displayed in a single line i want it to display it as a matrix format.

I my program i use string 1="bbabb" and string 2="aaabb" i compare each value and build a matrix accordingly with give me 25 values...but when displayed in my text area it show it like that "0000000100001000102101013" but i want to display it like that

```
0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 2 1
0 1 0 1 3
```

I am quite new to java.Can someone explain me the logic or give me a sample code where i can change the first string format to the second one.Thank you

Comment: Please always give something what you tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append a newline `"\n"` in between each row, when using your StringBuilder, e.g.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("row1");
sb.append("\n");
sb.append("row2");
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Obviously, adapt the above to fit in with your nested `for` loops...

Answer (score 0):

You need to print a line feed after each row and separate each element. e.g.

```
for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
   for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      // print your element matrix[r][c]
      System.out.print(" ");
   }
   System.out.println(""); // <-- LINE FEED AT THIS POINT
}
```

(or append to your `StringBuilder` etc.). Note that `println()` prints your string and a line feed. `print()` just prints the string.

Comment: i already did that what i want is when print it looks that the number of printed characters is equal to the row size then it continues to print on next line

Comment: I think the above gives everything that you need, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Its probable that you are missing a `System.out.println()` after the inner loop ends. You need to add that, to move your next row gets printed in a new line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Since you are using a `StringBuilder` to store your output, then you can append a `newline` to it at the same place (After inner loop): -

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
    }
    builder.append("\n");
}
```